# Randomly sample values from a pool so that the sum is less than a threshold in R

Tags: r, simulation

Let's say we have a pool of values and I want to sample random number of values from this pool, so that the sum of these values is between two thresholds. I want to design a function in R to implemented that.

```
pool = data.frame(ID = letters, value = sample(1:5, size = 26, replace = T))
> print(pool)
   ID  value
1  a     1
2  b     4
3  c     4
4  d     2
5  e     2
6  f     4
7  g     5
8  h     5
9  i     4
10 j     3
11 k     3
12 l     5
13 m     3
14 n     2
15 o     3
16 p     4
17 q     1
18 r     1
19 s     5
20 t     1
21 u     2
22 v     4
23 w     5
24 x     2
25 y     4
26 z     1
```

I want to randomly sample what ever number of IDs so that the sum of values for these IDs are between two thresholds, let's say between 8 and 10 (including the two boundaries). The expected outcome should be like these:

- c("a", "b", "c")
- c("f", "g")
- c("a", "d", "e", "j", "k")

I think this question has not been asked previously. Does anyone have clues?

Comment: This basically seems like the [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) which is NP-hard so no easy, general solution exists for solving such a problem. At least that's the case if you want to evenly sample from all possible subsets. If you want to conditionally re-sample until the threshold condition is met, there might be a different workaround, but that would have a different sample space.

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks. Yes I think I can figure out loops to sample from this pool until the threshold is met. I am just wondering if there is other ways to work and I don't have to use inefficient loops.

Comment: Loops aren't necessarily inefficient. Do you have an existing loop based solution? Do you need help improving it? Is speed your only concern at this point? I don't think am efficient general solution exists with or without loops unless I don't understand your exact problem.

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks. I don't have an existing loop, but what I had in mind was generate random numbers from 1:upper_threshold, and then sample this random number of values from pool until the requirement is met. This is especially inefficient when the random number equals upper_threshold, since it is almost impossible to sample upper_threshold of values to meet the condition.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach where I shuffle the input and check the cumulative sum of the shuffled output to look for an acceptable sum.

If a subset of that initial sequence happens to work, it outputs that sequence (in this manifestation, the longest sequence under the max threshold). If it doesn't work, it reshuffles and looks again, up to the max number of iterations.

```
set.seed(42)
library(dplyr)
sample_in_range <- function(src_tbl, min_sum = 8, max_sum = 10, max_iter = 100) {
  for(i in 1:max_iter) {
    output <- src_tbl %>% 
      sample_n(nrow(src_tbl)) %>%
      mutate(ID = as.character(ID),
             cuml = cumsum(value)) %>%
      filter(cuml <= max_sum)
    if(max(output$cuml) >= min_sum) return(output)
  }
}

output <- sample_in_range(pool)
output
  ID value cuml
1  k     3    3
2  w     2    5
3  z     4    9
4  t     1   10

output %>% pull(ID)
[1] "k" "w" "z" "t"
```

Comment: If it's important to get a more even sample among possible subsets, you could add a step here to identify the range of rows where the cumulative total is between thresholds and filter up to a random step in that range. I suspect that's not perfectly uniform, but the math of that is beyond my current understanding.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This works for me. I'll wait until no better solution pop up and then accept your answer.